# Why am I not hearing frequencies of range 14 kHz-15 kHz?

Tags: acoustics, frequency, biophysics

Recently, a Radio Station ([Red FM, 93.5](http://www.redfm.in/delhi/)) started a campaign called *"RED FM bajao Machar Bhagao"* (English: Play RED FM, scare away mosquitoes). In this, they claim to be broadcasting some frequencies in the range of 14 kHz-15 kHz, which irritate mosquitoes since these frequencies belong to dragonfly which eat them. They have been broadcasting this since Monday, and have received a lot of positive feedback. (If you understand Hindi, see their [FB feed](http://www.facebook.com/RJPankyandRJAshishRedFM)) . So, it seems to be working for some people.

But, why are those frequencies not audible to the people (and me)? I am 16 and my audible range is 20 Hz-20 kHz, but I just can't hear them. Why?

Comment: Do you *know* you can hear up to 20 KHz? (Even some young people can't.) Do you know for sure your radio can play frequencies that high? (Many speakers can't, and presumably some digital filters will remove the sound anyway.) Is there independent verification (not confirmation bias from people who want to believe this works) that they actually are transmitting at that frequency (which is at the limit of what FM can do, at least in the US)?

Comment: They say that their transponder limit is 15 KHz. And, I have no idea about the frequencies that my radio can play. For verification, toady mayors of North Delhi Municipal Corporation and South Delhi Municipal Corporation thanked them over the phone. So, they should be doing this.. Also, see this [article](http://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-20669080).

Comment: They have posted on their FB Feed: *Majority of ‪#‎Delhi‬ thinks Red FM is India's First Mosquito Repellent station. What do you think? WhatsApp us on +91 7531935935.*

Comment: If there's any sort of background noise you can't really hear anything above 10-12 KHz.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about human perception of some radio transmission.

Comment: @ACuriousMind please advice me where to ask this then as well.

Answer (score 3):

Run this to determine which frequency range(s) you can hear http://onlinetonegenerator.com/hearingtest.html If you can hear 14kHz-15kHz then the problem is with the radio or transmitter otherwise it is your hearing

I imagine that loss of hearing at an intermediate frequency would be rare especially if it is in both ears. My bet would be with poor speaker response so try with headphones if possible.

Comment: This is a bit simplistic (but it's not my downvote). I agree that there are many possible explanations - any component in the chain might be responsible, including the transmitter, receiver, amplifier, speaker, and observer. I have used a cheap ($2.99) app on my iPhone in the past to observe sounds too high for me to hear: SignalSpy gives a spectral rendering of the signal picked up by the microphone, and would show whether the 14 / 15 kHz signal is present "in the air". That takes all the guesswork / biology out of the equation.